# useEffect Missing Dependencies for Mount and Unmount

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in my code...

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, {capture: true})
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, {capture: true})
}, []);
```

To my understanding this how to fire events only when the component mounts/unmounts. However, when I use this I get a warning saying that this is missing `handleClick` as a dependency? Is this an expected warning when using `useEffect()` this way or is there something wrong with my approach?

After some searching around I saw a post suggesting to move the function into `useEffect` which I then tried

```
    useEffect(() => {
        function handleClick(e) {
            // click on node or any of its children
            if (node.current.contains(e.target)){ return }
            // otherwise the code below will execute when clicking off of node
            onOutsideClick();
        }

        // add event listener on mount
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClick, {capture: true});
        // clean up on unmount
        return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClick, {capture: true});
    
    }, []);
```

But now the warning is for `onOutsideClick` which is a prop set by another component and passed to the handler.

I only want this to run when the component mounts and unmounts so how can I resolve this? I have seen other posts that mention occasionally disabling the messages for certain parts of code but that doesn't seem desirable

Update: found some useful info about this in the [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

So with that, my current solution seems to be fine but would like some feedback on the solution.

The current solution involves passing `onOutsideClick` to the dependency array which satisfies the warning. Now the issue is that each time the parent component renders and sets `onOutsideClick`, our `useEffect` will re-render which is unnecessary. To resolve this I chose to set the callback passed to `onOutsideClick` with `useCallback()` which will prevent the re-render.

```
const handleOutsideClick = useCallback(() => setState(null), []);
...
<OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={ handleOutsideClick }>...</OutsideClickHandler>
```

Comment: Where does the `mounted` variable come from? Is that a state variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this goes when component mounted you dont need to check anything
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, {capture: true})
    
    // this will fire when component unmounts
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick, {capture: true})
}, []);
```

Example

```
useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
        };
    }, []);
```